# Visual basic System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to make a login form and keep getting this error:

> Visual basic System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one
>   or more required parameters.'

I'm using an access database with vb and everything is spelled correctly but I keep getting this error?

```
Private Sub Btn_Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Login.Click
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (Username = @sUsername) and (Password = @sPassword)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sUsername", Txt_Username.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sPassword", Txt_Password.Text)

            Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()

            If rs.Read Then
                PublicFirstname = rs("Firstname")
                PublicStaffID = rs("StaffID")
                'PublicAccessLevel = rs("AccessLevel")
                frmMainMenu.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Sorry, incorrect log in details entered")
            End If
            rs.Close()
```

**EDIT:**

Changed my code but still getting the same error:

```
If DbConnect() Then
    Using SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        With SQLCmd
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (Username = ?) and ([Password] = ?)"
            .Parameters.Add("@sUsername", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Username.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@sPassword", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Password.Text

            Using rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()
                If rs.Read Then
                Else
                    MsgBox("Sorry, incorrect log in details entered")
                End If
                rs.Close()
            End Using
        End With
    End Using
End If
```

Comment: Try wrapping password in [ ]'s `.CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (Username = @sUsername) and ([Password] = @sPassword)"` Password is a reserved keyword in OleDb

Comment: That still doesn't work anything else i could try?

Comment: Hallo, on what line you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here.

1. [`OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) does not support named parameters with `CommandType` set to `Text`.
   The order they are supplied is substantial.
2. [`PASSWORD`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE) is a reserved word in ms-access.
   Put it in square brackets.

Other things to enhance.

- Use `Using` for the `OleDbCommand` and the `OleDbDataReader`.
- Don't store passwords in clear-text.

So your code should look like following:

```
Using SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
    With SQLCmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (Username = ?) and ([Password] = ?)"
        .Parameters.Add("@sUsername", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Username.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@sPassword", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt_Password.Text

        Using rs As OleDbDataReader = .ExecuteReader()
            If rs.Read Then
            Else
                MsgBox("Sorry, incorrect log in details entered")
            End If
            rs.Close()
        End Using
    End With
End Using
```

**EDIT:**

As the column names are not `Username` and `Password` but `sUsername` and `sPassword`, you have to change the `CommandText` as follows:

```
.CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (sUsername = ?) and (sPassword = ?)"
```

Comment: Isn't sPassword ok with Access though?

Comment: Yes, but the column-name seems to be `Password`. To use it as colum-name you have to put it in square brackets: `[Password]`

Comment: I tried that and now i get System.InvalidCastException: 'The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.' as an error

Comment: Sorry, the parameters need to be added differently. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ive tried that again and i have my original error again the System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: Please double-check your code. Did you replace the parameter-names in the `CommandText` with a question mark, like in my answer?

Comment: one sec keeps messing up

Comment: Sorry cant seem to change it , it looks the same as yours and i still get the same error as before

Comment: oh there we go its changed

Comment: Strange, I've created a test-database with the same table and column names as in your question and tested it here. It works...

Comment: What does the connection string look like? Please add it to the question.

Comment: ive created a Modmain with all this in do you mean the path to the database?

Comment: The path looks like this Public Const DataBasePath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\bob\Desktop\VB\EasyCarRentalSystem v1\EasyCarDataBase.mdb';Persist Security Info=False;"

Comment: I have just one last idea. The column names in the table `Tbl_Staff` aren't `Username` and `Password` but something else...

Comment: in the database the column names are sUsername and sPassword

Comment: i dont understand why i would use a ? instead of @sUsername?

Comment: Then your statement should be: `.CommandText = "Select * From Tbl_Staff Where (sUsername = ?) and (sPassword = ?)"`

Comment: Access does not use named parameters, they are just placeholders to denote that a parameter will be supplied, ? is the correct way of setting a parameter for it but @Name will work in most cases, you just have to remember to supply the parameters in the order they appear in the statement.

Comment: I will add that I prefer @Name because it makes it easier to understand when reading the statement in code, but that's the only benefit it has in Access.