# "No value given for one or more required parameters" error using OleDbCommand

Tags: sql, vb.net, prepared-statement, oledb, oledbcommand

I am trying to update a record in MS Access using VB.net. This code will be under the "Delivered" button. When I try to run it, it shows the "No value given for one or more required parameters" error. Here is my code:

```
Private Const strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Traicy\Downloads\MWL(11-30-2021)\MadeWithLove\MadeWithLove\MadeWithLove.mdb;"
ReadOnly conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

Public Sub DeliveredUpdate()
    Const SQL As String = "UPDATE DELIVERY SET delivery_status =  @status"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)

    ' Update parameter
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Delivered")

    ' Open connection, update, then close connection
    Try
        conn.Open()
        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
            MsgBox("The delivery status was successfully updated.")
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The usual reason for this error is a missing or misspelled value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual basic System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564802/visual-basic-system-data-oledb-oledbexception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-r)

Comment: Before you run the query, it needs a `WHERE` clause, otherwise it will update *all* the records at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare connections or commands outside of the method where they are used. These database objects use unmanaged resources. They release these resources in their `Dispose` methods. The language provides `Using` blocks to handle this.

As mentioned in comments by Andrew Morton, you should have a `Where` clause to tell the database which record to update. This would contain the primary key of the record. I guessed at a name for the field, `OrderID`. Check your database for the real field name.

Access does not use named parameters but you can use names for readability. Access will be able to recognize the parameters as long as they are added to the `Parameters` collection in the same order that they appear in the sql string. In some databases the `Add` method is superior to `AddWithValue` because it doesn't leave the datatype to chance.

It is a good idea to separate your database code from your user interface code. If you want to show a message box in your `Catch` put the `Try` blocks in the UI code. This way your function can be used in a web app or mobile app without rewriting.

```
Public Function DeliveredUpdate(ID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim recordsUpdated As Integer
    Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE DELIVERY SET delivery_status =  @status Where OrderID = @Id;"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "Delivered"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID
        conn.Open()
        recordsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using 'closes and disposes the command and connection
    Return recordsUpdated
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Dim id As Integer = 1 'not sure where you are getting this value from
    Try
        retVal = DeliveredUpdate(id)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If retVal > 0 Then
        MsgBox("The delivery status was successfully updated.")
    End If
End Sub
```