# Oledb No Value Given for one or more required parameters VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? I am a complete novice here and this is the first time I have tried writing something in quite a while,

The below code should be updating two fields in an access database

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestButton.Click
    'connects application to database
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DatabasePath\database.accdb"
    Dim SqlString As String = "update SaintStaff set [StaffHours]=[@CAHours],[RecordedTime]=[@Time] where [StaffName] = " & Label2.Text & ""

    'updates record in  SaintStaff table.
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@CAHours]", Label6.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[@Time]", Label10.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I am getting the following error
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

and its highlighting the cmd text on each line, I cant tell what I am doing wrong, can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual basic System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564802/visual-basic-system-data-oledb-oledbexception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-r)

Comment: Don't put brackets around parameter names. Also don't concatenate query strings as this opens your application for sql injection attacks. That's what parameters are made for.

Comment: If you do string concatenation, appending an empty string makes no difference. But you must put single quotes around SQL strings: `"update ... where [StaffName] = '" & Label2.Text & "'"`. But intriducing a 3rd parameter is to be preferred (without quotes this time): `"update ... where StaffName = @StaffName"`

Comment: Thankyou @MatSnow changing the cmd parameter to cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAHours", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Label6.Text  fixed part of the problem

Comment: Thank you @OlivierJacot-Descombes for the StaffName variable suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Question was answered by MatSnow and olivier-jacot-descombes in the comments, the correct code looks as follows

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestButton.Click
    'connects application to database
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DatabasePath\Database.accdb"
    Dim SqlString As String = "update SaintStaff set StaffHours = @CAHours, RecordedTime = @Time where StaffName = @staffname "

    'updates record in  SaintStaff table.
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAHours", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Label6.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Label10.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Staffname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Label2.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)